# When drafting a new Word page, the line spacing shows as double spaced, even though I only push enter once

Tags: format, microsoft-word-2010

When typing a new document in Word 2010, when I press the "Enter" key, the text on the screen jumps down as if I pressed the key twice (or want a double space) inbetween the text lines.

Example, when I type an address to print an envelope, on the screen it looks like this:

```
  Mary Smith

  123 Maple Lane

  New Town, CA  12345
```

But when I highlight the above text and click on my envelope icon, the envelope prints in single space (which is what I want), but I also want to see it that way on the screen -- NOT double-spaced.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the new default style added in Word 2007.

The default uses 1.15 line spacing for hard line breaks.

See Microsoft's [Why did the line spacing change in Word?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/why-did-the-line-spacing-change-in-word-HA010231027.aspx) for an explanation and a resolution to make it look/act as Word 2003 did.

In general you should be able to just highlight the section you want to have in regular spacing, and then pick the second style in the list in the Ribbon ("No Spacing", between "Normal" and "Heading 1"):

[image: Styles Ribbon]

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UF9HwSHRDk) explaining how to adjust line spacing under Word 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to Microsoft's setting the default Paragraph Spacing After to 10pt (instead of 0pt in the older versions) and the line spacing to 1.15 (instead of single in previous versions).

To fix this permanently so that all new documents are fixed:

1. Click on the Home Ribbon.
2. Click the little Dialog Launcher arrow in the corner of the Paragraph group.
3. Change the spacing after from 10pt to 0.
4. Change the Line Spacing to single.
5. Click the "Default..." button, and choose "OK" when prompted.

Now, all new documents will be setup without all this extra spacing. (Make sure to highlight all your text if you want this to fix the current document too!)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't modify the style, nor would I switch to no spacing.

It's just better to make a new style. Or in this case, switch to the style named **Word 2003**.

[image]